# Modify array values based on the duplicate occurrence

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, ranking

I need to sort an array based on the duplicate occurrences. For each duplicate occurrence the sequence must apply the pattern rule specified in the output arrays.

Input value  : `[ 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 ]`
Output value : `[ 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 7 ]`

Input value  : `[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 ]`
Output value : `[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 5 ,6, 6, 8 ]`

Input value  : `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]`
Output value : `[1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 6]`

Output needs to be dynamically set based on the count of duplicate values in the output. Say if after `1` there are `3` `2's` then after `2` the sequence must have to have `5`.

Think of it like this scenario if there are `2` `4th` position in an exam result then then there will be no `5th` position so after two ties for number `4` there will be `5th` position.

Another example can be if there are `3` `4th` position then there will be no `5th` and `6th` position so the next position will be `7th` position.

Comment: I assume by `[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 5 ,6, 6, 7 ]` you mean `[ 1, 2, 2, 2, 5 ,6, 6, 8 ]` since the 8th number is not supposed to be `7`

Comment: yes that was a mistake. sorry about that. changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const rank = arr => arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  acc.push(cur === arr[i - 1] ? acc[i - 1] : i + 1);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(rank([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]));
console.log(rank([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]));
console.log(rank([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]));
```